# how can i input more than 10 integers?

Tags: java

how can i input more than 10 integers in Database when i input more than 10 integers this will appear  Number Format Exception: For input string: can everyone help me?
this is my code

```java
try {
    i = Integer.valueOf(cmb.getText());
    String conV = String.valueOf(i);
    n = a1.getText();
    s = a2.getText();

    rs.moveToInsertRow();

    rs.updateString("STUDENTNO", conV);
    rs.updateString("NAME", n);
    rs.updateString("COURSE", s);
    rs.insertRow();
    Refresh_RS_STMT();

    jTable4.clearSelection();
    showAll();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Student has been saved!");

} catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,err);
}
```

Comment: 32-bit integer number cannot have more than 10 digits. On Java level you can surpass this limitation by using Strings or BigIntegers, on database level it depends on the specific DB you are using.

Comment: You meant you cannot insert 10 integers or an integer with more than 10 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
  i = Integer.valueOf(cmb.getText().trim())
```

to avoid "whitespaces" by "trimming" your input string.

Or catch the `NumberFormatException` which may be thrown in `Integer.valueOf()` and show us the exception.